# Pick a random item from a list and then delete any subsequent list items containing the same words as the randomly picked item?

Tags: list, applescript

I'm making a script to create a food menu by randomly picking dishes off of a list 7 times. However, I would like to make it so that it doesn't pick any similar dishes. For instance, if 'Lamb Chops' was chosen as `dish1`, then `dish2` would be a random item from the same list with all the options including 'lamb' and 'chops' removed. Then if `dish2` was 'Spaghetti Bolognese', then `dish3` would be chosen from the same list excluding 'lamb', 'chops', 'spaghetti', and 'bolognese', and so on and so on. Can anyone help?

-Thanks.

Comment: show your approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm somewhat rusty with AppleScript, so excuse me if I make mistakes.
To break down what you must do,

1) **Choose a random item**

```
-- The initial menuItems we start off with
set menuItems to {"Lamb Chops", "Lamb", "Chops", "Spaghetti Bolognese", "Spaghetti", "Bolognese"}

set randomItemNum to random number from 1 to count of menuItems
set randomItem to item randomItemNum of menuItems as string
```

2) **Repeat through `menuItems`** so we can exclude items that contain a word from `randomItem`
We'll use this subroutine to split strings:

```
on splitString(theString, theDelimiter)
    -- save delimiters to restore old settings
    set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    -- set delimiters to delimiter to be used
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    -- create the array
    set theArray to every text item of theString
    -- restore the old setting
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    -- return the result
    return theArray
end splitString
```

and now we can easily split strings, lets continue with **the reconstruction of the menu**:

```
-- This loops through menuItems, and we can use menuItem to access the current looped item
-- We'll use this to reconstruct menuItems, but excluding what we need

set newMenuItems to {}
repeat with menuItem in menuItems
    -- Get words from randomItem
    -- For example, if randomItem is "Lamb Chops", it will return {"Lamb","Chops"}
    set menuItemWords to splitString(randomItem, " ")

    -- This is the conditional that will determine to include menuItem or not
    -- Feel free to change this to get the outcome you want
    if menuItemWords does not contain menuItem as string and menuItem does not contain menuItemWords then

        -- And this conditional to not re-add the randomItem
        -- However, it does it to one word items in the previous if statement
        -- Note: Without using "as string" to menuItem it doesn't work correctly, not sure why          
       if menuItem as string is not equal to randomItem then
            set the end of newMenuItems to menuItem
        end

    end

end repeat
-- Now we've finished creating a new menu with the changes we want, set it to the main one
set menuItems to newMenuItems
```

And, now it should work.
You might also want to **examine the results easily**, in which case, you can use this subroutine to concatenate the arrays into a string:

```
on arrayToString(theArray, theSeperator)
    set arrayString to ""
    repeat with theItem in theArray
        if arrayString is equal to "" then
            set arrayString to theItem
        else
            set arrayString to arrayString & theSeperator & theItem
        end if
    end repeat
end arrayToString
```

and just display the results before you set the menu to the new one.

```
........

display alert "I've picked " & randomItem & " for you." message "Old menu:
" & arrayToString(menuItems, ", ") & "
New menu:
" & arrayToString(newMenuItems, ", ")

-- Now we've finished creating a new menu with the changes we want and displayed the results, set it to the main one
set menuItems to newMenuItems
```

---

You can also loop through the menu items 7 times by warping the code in a `repeat 7 times` after specifying the initial menuItem, and a check to exit the repeat if menuItems is empty, like this:

```
on splitString(theString, theDelimiter)
    ...
end splitString

-- The initial menuItems we start off with
set menuItems to {"Lamb Chops", "Lamb", "Chops", "Spaghetti Bolognese", "Spaghetti", "Bolognese"}

-- Repeat statement to loop 7 times
repeat 7 times
  -- If menuItems is empty, exit the repeat
  if count of menuItems is 0 then
      exit repeat
  end if

  set randomItemNum to random number from 1 to count of menuItems
  set randomItem to item randomItemNum of menuItems as string

  set newMenuItems to {}
  repeat with menuItem in menuItems
      ...
  end repeat
  -- Now we've finished creating a new menu with the changes we want, set it to the main one
  set menuItems to newMenuItems

-- This is the end of loop for 7 times
end repeat
```

---

I hope this helps.
If you need any other help, or there's an error, please comment below and l'll try my best.

---

**Edit**:
Here is the complete code that should do what you need, it repeats 7 times and shows the user a list of the selected dishes when completed:

```
on splitString(theString, theDelimiter)
    -- save delimiters to restore old settings
    set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    -- set delimiters to delimiter to be used
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    -- create the array
    set theArray to every text item of theString
    -- restore the old setting
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    -- return the result
    return theArray
end splitString

on arrayToString(theArray, theSeperator)
    set arrayString to ""
    repeat with theItem in theArray
        if arrayString is equal to "" then
            set arrayString to theItem
        else
            set arrayString to arrayString & theSeperator & theItem
        end if
    end repeat
end arrayToString

-- The menu after you finish looping to show the user
set yourMenu to {}

-- The initial menuItems we start off with
set menuItems to {"Lamb Chops", "Lamb", "Chops", "Spaghetti Bolognese", "Spaghetti", "Bolognese"}

-- Repeat statement to loop 7 times
repeat 7 times
    -- If menuItems is empty, exit the repeat
    if (count of menuItems) is 0 then
        exit repeat
    end if

    set randomItemNum to random number from 1 to count of menuItems
    set randomItem to item randomItemNum of menuItems as string

    -- This loops through menuItems, and we can use menuItem to access the current looped item
    -- We'll use this to reconstruct menuItems, but excluding what we need
    set newMenuItems to {}
    repeat with menuItem in menuItems
        -- Get words from randomItem
        -- For example, if randomItem is "Lamb Chops", it will return {"Lamb","Chops"}
        set menuItemWords to splitString(randomItem, " ")

        -- This is the conditional that will determine to include menuItem or not
        -- Feel free to change this to get the outcome you want
        if menuItemWords does not contain menuItem as string and menuItem does not contain menuItemWords then

            -- And this conditional to not re-add the randomItem
            -- However, it does it to one word items in the previous if statement
            -- Note: Without using "as string" to menuItem it doesn't work correctly, not sure why          
            if menuItem as string is not equal to randomItem then
                set the end of newMenuItems to menuItem
            end if

        end if

    end repeat

    -- Now we've finished creating a new menu with the changes we want, set it to the main one
    set menuItems to newMenuItems
    set the end of yourMenu to randomItem

    -- This is the end of loop for 7 times
end repeat

set itemSelected to (choose from list yourMenu with prompt "Here's your menu.")
display alert "You selected " & itemSelected & "."
```

Comment: @TheTobemonster It appears that you never set MenuItems2 to anything, so it's an empty array. In the line, `set randomItem2 to item randomItemNum2 of MenuItems2 as string` you're asking to set `set randomItem2 to item [random number] of { [nothing] } as string`

Comment: I read this and a lot of it is beyond my knowledge of Applescript. I wanted it to choose 7 different unrelated dishes and display them in a dialog box. From what I understood, I pieced together the following script: https://www.dropbox.com/s/upvdzfi6a6kv6od/Menu%20Picker%20V2.scpt?dl=0. However, I always get the same error "Can’t make item 1 of {} into type string." I was hoping you could tell me what is wrong and how I can fix it? Sorry if I seem dumb here, my knowledge of Applescript isn't too great. -Thanks

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work? I changed all the `set randomItem2 to item randomItemNum2 of MenuItems2 as string` to `set randomItem2 to item randomItemNum2 of MenuItems as string` in every line. This just runs for about 30 seconds and then crashes the script editor without any errors. Again, really sorry if I sound stupid here.

Comment: l'll try my best to fix your script, just I'm a little busy right now. I've also added the complete code at the end of my explanation, maybe it could also help you.

Comment: I've read of your script, and it seems your repeating yourself to get 7 items. You just need to use a repeat for 7 times, don't repeat code when you don't have to. Give me a few minutes, l'll change the code at the end to fit your needs.

Comment: Okay, check the code at the end now, it should do what you ask. (Just change `menuItems` to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Compact version:

```
set menuItems to {"Lamb Chops", "Lamb", "Chops", "Spaghetti Bolognese", "Spaghetti", "Bolognese"}
set randomItem to item (random number from 1 to count menuItems) of menuItems
```

If the amount of items is constant in the list, you can even go like this:

```
set randomItem to item (random number from 1 to 6) of {"Lamb Chops", "Lamb", "Chops", "Spaghetti Bolognese", "Spaghetti", "Bolognese"}
```